# IIS AspNetMembershipProvider Website migration issue

Tags: .net, iis

I'm having trouble with the IIS7 AspNetMembershipProvider. I usually write the code on my desktop and publish the file to a drive and host on my laptop it was working fine. But recently I got an issue about the AspNetMembershipProvider. It keep giving me the error about cannot find LocalSqlServer.

But I was able to host on my desktop just fine.
And I checked I did not have AspNetMembershipProvider in my web.config.
It is coming from MS.NET Framework's machine.config

Is there any suggestion on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance